# How do you copy a formula down a column with the org-mode spreadsheet

Tags: org-mode

After using `C-c =` to enter a formula, I want that formula to apply to every row in that column. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My personal preference is to add a column [formula directly](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-formulas.html#Column-formulas) into the cell, instead of having to remember so many keyboard shortcuts.

Just start typing into the cell, starting with a `=` sign. For example, in column 3 type `=$1+$2` and that formula will apply to all of the column directly.

You need to `C-c C-c` to actually apply the formula and calculate results.

For a single cell (non-column) formula, start with `:=` instead.

Comment: Hmm, if i do that, with the "=" sign, it will only calculate one cell, not the whole column...

Comment: Per @Coliban's comment, I had to also execute C-c C-c on the #+TBLRM line as well otherwise only the one row is effected

Comment: @Coliban You can force it to calculate all the fields with C-u C-c *

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is to use `C-3 C-c =` where `3` is the number of rows you want the formula to apply to.

```
| 3 | 4 |   |
| 2 | 8 |   |
```

If I `C-2 C-c =` in the column after the `4`. I can input my formula of `$1+$2` which will cascade down to each row, giving me the result of

```
| 4 | 3 |  7 |
| 2 | 8 | 10 |
#+TBLFM: $3=$1+$2
```

You are also free to just add `#+TBLFM: $3=$1+$2` to the bottom of your table. You can force the formula to revaluate its values with `C-c C-c` when your point is anywhere over the formula.

Answer (score 2):

[`C-u C-c C-c` re-applies all formulas](http://orgmode.org/manual/Updating-the-table.html#Updating-the-table).

For example, given

```
| 3 |  4 | _ |
| 2 |  8 |   |
| 1 | 12 |   |
```

(where `_` marks the location of the cursor) you could type `C-c =`<sup>1</sup>, then enter a formula such as

```
$3=$1+$2
```

So the table looks like:

```
| 3 |  4 | 7 |
| 2 |  8 |   |
| 1 | 12 |   |
#+TBLFM: $3=$1+$2
```

Now typing `C-u C-c C-c` yields

```
| 3 |  4 |  7 |
| 2 |  8 | 10 |
| 1 | 12 | 13 |
```

<sup>1</sup>Alternatively, use `C-c '` to open a formula editing buffer, write and/or edit the formulas, then close the buffer (with `C-x` `C-s`) instead. I find this more convenient since you can use all emacs commands in the buffer, instead of just the limited set you can use in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the point on the cell with the single formula result and then hit `C-u C-c *`